# Pivot sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I've SQL Server 2005 table 
COMPETITOR (Id, Title, cDate, Price)
I want to format the query so that its view in Gridview will be like this:
[image]

Please help me writing the sql query.

Comment: You have to specify what RDBMS you are in since OLAP queries are very DB dependent these days...

Comment: I'm using SQL Sever 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL 2005 supports `PIVOT` - the Books Online doc is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.90).aspx

The main shortcoming I've found with the `PIVOT` stuff is that you **must** specify the column names, although you can use a query beforehand and inject the values into a varchar variable and then execute that.